# Regex expression to match only html p tags or no tags

Tags: html, regex

I need a regex expression that matches only the first p tag (`/<p>(.*)<\/p>/`) or the first line that does not start with `<` if it doesn't find a p tag before this. I tried this : `/(?!<)(.*)||<p>(.*)<\/p>/` but then this selects the first line regardless of if there is a `<` at the begging of the line.

How can I make it only select the first line that starts with a p tag or without any tags.

For example it should select `<p>Text</p>` here:

```
<h2>Tittle</h2>
<p>Text</p>
```

and Text here:

```
Text
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

Comment: If possible, I'd considering using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use `.*` like this. It will match more than you will expect. I.e. on

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>More text</p><p>Another text</p>
```

your match will be

```
More text</p><p>Another text
```

better use `<p>[^<]*<\/p>` to really match the inner content of a single `<p>` (if there is no other html inside - if there is, use a HTML-Parser is way easier)

Second - your example seems to common. If it is just "text" as "first element(s), the following pattern will work out: `(<p>[^<]+<\/p>|\w+)`

But there are various questions unanswered: Are tags allowed in the line "after" Text - should they be matched, or just the text? Can HTML appear inside `<p>` tags? Should a line with *non-valid* html-tags be matched? etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 (<p>(?:(?!</?p>).)+</p>)
```